# Error in `step_log()`: When trying to make predictions with my model

Tags: r, prediction, tidymodels, r-recipes

I'm trying to make predictions with my testing data using my finalized workflow. But whenever I try using the predict function, it gives me this error:

```
Error in `step_log()`:
! The following required column is missing from `new_data` in step 'log_79Q8u': shares.
```

The shares variable is present in my testing dataset.

Do I need to cahnge my recipe and retune my model?? This is for my final and I really need to resolve this error would appreciate any advice!!

My code for the recipe and the prediction is below:

```
# recipe 
recipe_kc <- recipe(shares ~ ., data = articles_train) %>% 
  step_log(shares) %>% 
step_normalize(all_numeric_predictors()) %>%  
  step_zv(all_predictors()) 

# selecting best model
best_workflow <- bt_tuned %>% 
  extract_workflow_set_result("recipe3_bt") %>% 
  select_best(metric = "rmse", "rsq")

best_workflow

final_workflow <- bt_tuned %>% 
  extract_workflow("recipe3_bt") %>% 
  finalize_workflow(best_workflow)


final_fit <- fit(final_workflow, articles_train)


# using testing data
final_pred <- articles_test %>% 
  select(shares) %>% 
  bind_cols(predict(final_fit, new_data = articles_test)) %>% 
  mutate(
    .pred_log = .pred,
    .pred = 10^.pred_log
  ) %>% 
  summarize(.pred, shares, shares_log,.pred_log)
```

Comment: Difficult to help without a reproducible example, but is there a reason why you remove all variables except `shares` by running `select(shares)` before `predict()`?

Comment: @Phil I just wanted to select the predictor variable, regardless even if I just do predict() by itself, I am still getting that error. I can also post an example of my workflow for my model if that helps

Comment: Oh i see now, sorry never mind my initial question.

Comment: What would really help is an example of your data and your workflow using `dput()`.

Comment: more on reproducibility: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a problem because you are transforming the outcome inside the recipe. [It is generally advised](https://www.tmwr.org/recipes.html#skip-equals-true) that you don't perform simple transformations on the outcome inside the recipe and it can cause problems as you have seen.

Instead I recommend that you do the transformation before you split your data, this way you won't run into problem when the outcome isn't available to transform

```r
set.seed(3467) 
articles_split <- article %>%
  # Log the outcome
  mutate(shares = log(shares)) %>%
  initial_split()

articles_train <- training(articles_split)
```